# No lucene documents created when serializer added

Tags: lucene, spring-data-gemfire, geode, gfsh

I created lucene index in **gfsh** using the following command 
`create lucene index --name=myLucIndex --region=myRegion --field=title 
--analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer --serializer=a.b.c.MyLatLongSerializer`

My serializer is as follows :

```java
class MyLatLongSerializer implements LuceneSerializer<Book> {
@Override
  public Collection<Document> toDocuments(LuceneIndex luceneIndex, Book book) {

    logger.debug("inside custom lucene serializer ...");

    // Writes fields of Book into a document
    Document newDocument = new Document();
    newDocument.add(new StoredField("title", book.getTitle()));
    newDocument.add(new LatLonPoint("location", book.getLatitude(), book.getLongitude()));

    return Collections.singleton(newDocument);
  }
}
```

My spring boot configuration file is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@ClientCacheApplication
@EnableClusterDefinedRegions(clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
@EnableIndexing
public class BookConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "bookGemfireCache")
  ClientCacheConfigurer bookGemfireCache(
      @Value("${spring.data.geode.locator.host:localhost}") String hostname,
      @Value("${spring.data.geode.locator.port:10334}") int port) {

    // Get clientCache
  }

  @Bean
  Region<Long, Book> bookRegion(ClientCache clientCache) {
    logger.debug("inside regions ...");
    return clientCache.getRegion("myRegion");
  }

  @Bean
  LuceneService ukBikesLuceneService(ClientCache clientCache) {
    return LuceneServiceProvider.get(clientCache);
  }
}
```

I load data to geode using the following code :

```java
  bookRegion.putAll(Map<bookId, Book>);
```

`describe lucene index --name=myLucIndex --region=myRegion` then **document # 0** but when I create lucene index using the below command

```
create lucene index --name=myLucIndex --region=myRegion --field=title
--analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer
```

then load the data again, run

```
  describe lucene index --name=myLucIndex --region=myRegion
```

then **document # 96**.

I use spring data geode 2.1.8.RELEASE, geode-core 1.9.0, lucene-core 8.2.0

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Did you check the logs on the server side? Since lucene indexes are maintained asynchronously, and errors from your serializer will show up there.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Your comment helped. I could find NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/document/LatLonPoint error in /ServerOne/ServerOne.log

Comment: I upgraded lucene from 6.6.2 to 8.2.0  

while loading data to geode with the above lucene index, I see the below error in /myServer/myServer.log  Task failed with exception                                     
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.getPendingDeletions()Ljava/util/Set;                                           
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.<init>(IndexFileDeleter.java:212)  What am I done wrong here ?

Comment: deploy --dir=data --groups=myGroup didn't help resolve the error either.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/) currently uses [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) version [6.6.6](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/geode/gradle/plugins/DependencyConstraints.groovy#L206-L212) and you're using `lucene-core 8.2.0`, which is not backward compatible with major older versions like `6.X`, that's the reason why you're getting these exceptions. Everything should work just fine if you use the Lucene version shipped with Geode.

As a side note, there are current efforts to upgrade the Lucene version used by Geode, you can follow the progress through [GEODE-7039](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7309).

Hope this helps.